# Reverse the order of user inputted string

Tags: mips

goodafternoon, i made this code that takes in user input and reverses the order. the code works perfectly except when there is long user input such the alphabet. in this case the output excludes the last letter, i am unsure why this is and any insight would be greatly appreciated.

```
    .data
    .align 2
array:  .space  80
size:       .word       20
string: .space  20000
op:     .asciiz "Enter n, followed by n lines of text:"
prompt: .asciiz ""
text:       .asciiz "The values are:"
newline:    .asciiz "\n"

    .text
    .globl main
main:
    #prompt user for array length
    li  $v0,4
    la  $a0,op
    syscall
    jal new_line        #output newline

    #read in array count
    li  $v0,5
    syscall
    addi    $s0,$v0,0       #$v0 contains the integer we read

    add $t0,$zero,$zero #index of array
    addi    $t1,$zero,1     #counter=1
    la  $s2,string      #load address of string storage area

read_string:
    bgt $t1,$s0,L1      #if ($t1 > length) then array is done

    # prompt the user for next string
    li  $v0,4           
    la  $a0,prompt
    syscall

    #get the string
    move    $a0,$s2     #place to store string
    li  $a1,20
    li  $v0,8
    syscall

    #store pointer to string into array
    sw  $a0,array($t0)

    addi    $t0,$t0,4       #advance offset into pointer array
    addi    $t1,$t1,1       #advance iteration count
    addi    $s2,$s2,20      #advance to next string area
    
    j   read_string

#### here i want to print the array ####
L1:
    addi    $t1,$zero,1     #counter = 1

    #output the title
    la  $a0,text        
    li  $v0,4
    syscall
    jal new_line

while:
    addi    $t0,$t0,-4      #advance array index
    bgt $t1,$s0,done    #if no more strings to output then done
    lw  $t2,array($t0)  #get pointer to string

    #output the string
    li  $v0,4
    move    $a0,$t2
    syscall

    addi    $t1,$t1,1       #advance count
    j   while

new_line:
    la  $a0,newline
    li  $v0,4
    syscall
    jr  $ra

done:
    li  $v0,10
    syscall
```

if the user enters a n value of 26 and following lines a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z then the output should be z y x v u t s r q p o n m l k j i h g f e d c b a. However what is outputted is this: z y x v u t s r q p o n m l k j i h g f e d c b. so its missing the letter a

Comment: Your `array` only has space for 80 bytes (i.e. 20 word-size addresses).

Comment: @Michael i changed the array to hold space for 160 bytes (40 word-size addresses) however the issue is still occurring

Comment: Then I suppose you have some other bugs as well. Set some breakpoints in the print loop and see what happens when you run it.

Comment: if you made the space for string bigger as @Michael says, the code will work...

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, the problem is that you're ending the loop one pass too early.

```
while:
    addi    $t0,$t0,-4      #advance array index
    bgt $t1,$s0,done    #if no more strings to output then done
```

Here, you're effectively comparing `$s0` to 26, since that's the whole alphabet size.
But since you started `$t1` as equaling 1, you're encountering an "off-by-one" error most likely.

When compilers implement a loop like `while(count < 26)`, often they don't do this literally like you have done here. It's usually easier to do the following:

```
    #read in array count
    li  $v0,5
    syscall
    addi    $s0,$v0,1       #$v0 contains the integer we read plus 1.

# do your other stuff here

while:
    addi    $t0,$t0,-4      #advance array index
    lw  $t2,array($t0)  #get pointer to string

    #output the string
    li  $v0,4
    move    $a0,$t2
    syscall

    addi $s0,$s0,-1
    bnez $s0,while
```

Since you're only adding 1 to your count variable it's easier just to make it a downward for-loop (as I said eariler, a C compiler typically does this even if you declare the loop as a `while`.)

Sometimes you just need to adjust your loop counter by 1 and that may be enough to fix things.